# node using .insertId to get last insert returns 0 instead of auto increment id

Tags: mysql, node.js

in my code the insertId returns 0 rather than the auto_increment column, am I selecting the wrong value with `result[0]`

```
connection.query(stuff[prop], function (err, result) {
                        if (err) {
                            callback("err" + err);
                        } else {
                            var newid = result[0].insertId;
                            callback("done:"+newid);
                        }
```